# QGIS hide labels in layer panel

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have a line layer with a rule-based symbology. For every rule I use a marker line.

[image]

Can I hide single labels in my layers window?

I don´t want two of the same labels and I don´t want the markerline symbol in my layers window.

Could I hide it, too?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the expression string builder to sum up my rule based symbology in one rule.
Then I only get one label in the layers window.
[image]